# Solution | How To Create Dependency of Own Utility Project

Tags: spring-boot, maven, deployment, dependency-management, github-package-registry

By uploading it to GitHub's own package registry, you can easily use the relevant dependency in your project.

For applications written with Spring Boot + Maven, you can follow the steps below:

1. To enable deployment of the project on GitHub, you should add the following code block to the `pom.xml` file:

```
<distributionManagement>
   <repository>
      <id>github</id>
      <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/{username}/{repository-name}</url>
   </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

2. Then, you need to create a new token from the `https://github.com/settings/tokens` address. After that, you should add your information to the `settings.xml` file and place it in the `.m2` folder.

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>github</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>github</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>github</id>
                    <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/{username}/{repository-name}</url>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>github</id>
            <username>{username}</username>
            <password>{your-personal-token}</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

3. After completing the first two steps, the project should be present in a repository on GitHub. Therefore, you need to create a repository on GitHub for the project and then upload it there.
4. Once the project is available on GitHub, all you need to do is run the `mvn clean deploy` command in the directory where the project is located.

After this process is completed, you can access your project dependency through `https://github.com/{username}/{Brepository-name}/packages`. The relevant dependency example will already be available. You can add this dependency example to your project and use it like any other dependency.

```
<repositories>
   <repository>
      <id>{artifactId}</id>
      <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/{username}/{repository-name}</url>
   </repository>
</repositories>
```

> The important thing to remember is that only one dependency can be created for each version. If you want to create a new dependency for the same version, you need to delete the corresponding dependency on GitHub. After taking action on this, it would be very helpful if you share the outcome with me or provide feedback in case you encounter any issues.

> Additionally, if you have your own solutions, you can share them under this post as well!

Comment: This is not a question. If you want to share your knowledge, please ask a question and add an answer yourself.

Comment: @JFabianMeier thank you for your clarification. I understand that you are limited in adding comments to your own questions and can only respond from here. In this case, I appreciate your approach.

Comment: What @JFabianMeier meant was that you should split your text into two parts: Question and Answer. In StackOverflow it is perfectly OK to answer your own question. The solution should not be in the question. Similarly how I did it in https://stackoverflow.com/a/77171271/2886891 . There is even a checkbox "Answer your own question" when you are writing the question - so you may post your question and answer at the same time. In this case you should simply post the answer and then remove the solution from the question.