how to fix CloudSim-plus Build error on intellij IDE?
i have a problem with building my cloudsim plus, the Error is:
java: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Class com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCImport does not have member field 'com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree qualid'
and my maven version is 3.8.6 and JDK 22
i try to change maven version to 3.9.4 but cloudsim plus using 3.3.2
how could i solve it?

Seems to be a Lombok issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77171270/compilation-error-after-upgrading-to-jdk-21-nosuchfielderror-jcimport-does-n
